# Could this ActiveRecord/SQL statement in my code base be susceptible to SQL injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I was reading up on SQL injection attacks from the Rails Guides and was wondering if the below line could be susceptible to a SQL Injection attack:

```
accounts.where("lower(name) LIKE '%#{params[:query].downcase}%'")
```

If I read and understand the guide correctly, could a user do something like

```
 `'\''; DROP TABLE users;`
```

Would that drop my table?

------EDIT------

Same for these examples:

```
Account.where(id: account_id).first
current_user.actions.where(id: params[:clear_action_reminder]).first
edits.where.not(account_id: non_human_ids)
Rating.where(project_id: @project.id, account_id: current_user.id).first_or_initialize
```

These are of course application specific queries but because there is no `?` in the query could these all potentially be disastrous?

Comment: Any queries where you pass params through as arguments, rather than interpolating them into a string, will be sanitized by rails.  So, this is safe `current_user.actions.where(id: params[:clear_action_reminder]).first` and this is **not** safe `current_user.actions.where("id = #{params[:clear_action_reminder]}").first`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Account.where("lower(name) LIKE '%#{params[:query].downcase}%'")

Yes, the above query is **vulnerable**.
 
Building your own string from user input may expose your application to injection attacks.

Instead of passing a string to the conditions option, you can pass an array to sanitize tainted strings like this:

```
query = params[:query].downcase
Account.where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{query}%")
```

This will make your code safe & readable in complex queries. If `#where` is called with multiple arguments, these are treated as if they were passed as the elements of a single array. You can call with `hash` as well. Both `array` and `hash` are safe.

Your following queries are safe:

```
Account.where(id: account_id).first 
current_user.actions.where(id: params[:clear_action_reminder]).first
Edit.where.not(account_id: non_human_ids) 
Rating.where(project_id: @project.id, account_id: current_user.id).first_or_initialize
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sharvy. I don't know if you saw my edit but are the other ones susceptible as well?